# Remove job and kill process on timeout

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write some code (a function) where I can either run any cmdlet OR any process as a script block, but timeout if it takes longer than X seconds to run.

I think the cmdlet aspect is fine.  But for processes, I'm struggling.  In the below example if I take away the -wait from running notepad, it returns a process ID (which i could then kill) but of course the job finishes instantly.

If I put the -wait in, when it times out it returns nothing because the start-process command hasn't finished.  So I can't kill the launched process (notepad.exe).

Any pointers would be helpful - thanks.

```
$timeoutSeconds = 5

function Start-My-Process {
    param($ScriptBlock, $TimeoutSeconds)
     
    $job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock
    
    if($job | Wait-Job -Timeout $TimeoutSeconds){  
        $returnCode = $job | Receive-Job
    } else {
        write-host "timed out"        
        #cannot get process ID to kill?     
        #& taskkill /PID $returnCode /f /t
    }
    $job |Remove-Job -Force    
}

$code = {
  #start-sleep -Seconds 3
  return (start-process notepad.exe -passthru -wait).Id
}

Start-My-Process $code $timeoutSeconds
```

Comment: why do you need to track processes when you can track jobs? $job.state

Answer (score 1):

The following doesn't (directly) apply to *GUI*(-subsystem) applications such as `Notepad`, but does apply to *console*(-subsystem) applications (which are more likely the ones you're trying to run in the context of a background [job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Jobs)):

- You don't need to kill any console-application child process launched *by direct invocation* from your job explicitly - it is automatically killed as part of (forcefully) removing the enclosing job with `Remove-Job -Force`.

If you do need to invoke GUI applications, there is no way around modifying their invocation inside the script block:

- In the simplest case, call via `cmd /c`, which makes the invocation *blocking*, however (in the context of the background job); e.g.:

  - `cmd /c Notepad`
- Otherwise, use [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) with `-PassThru` to launch the application and output the resulting process-information object from the job, where the caller can retrieve it via [`Receive-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/receive-job), and obtain the PID (process ID) from its `.Id` property.
  You can also use this technique if you want to *asynchronously* launch console applications from your job (at the expense of being able to directly capture their output).

Finally, note that *UWP applications* (typically obtained from Microsoft Store) are often launched in a manner where the original process delegates to a different, non-child process and then exits right away, which makes them impossible to track based on the original process' ID.